# Asp.net C# DropDownList Filtering Multiple

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I have 3 DropDownBoxes I was successful to make the first two to work which is depending on the selection of the first DropDownList "Academic, Professional but what is not working is the 3rd DropDownBox its not showing the data that need to be inserted not sure where I went wrong.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    if (value == "Professional")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select One", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Continuing - Professional", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Fixed Term", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Casual", string.Empty));
    }
    else if (value == "Academic")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select One", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Continuing - Academic", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Fixed Term", string.Empty));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Sessional", string.Empty));
    }
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();

    if (value == "Continuing - Professional")
    {
        DropDownList5.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("WORKED", string.Empty));

    }
    else if (value == "Fixed Term")
    {
        DropDownList5.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Worked, string.Empty));

    }
```

Aspx Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Staff.aspx.cs" Inherits="Staff" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        Staffing - Please Complete the Following</div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 120px; top: 114px; position: absolute" Text="Position"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 344px; top: 114px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 109px; top: 162px; position: absolute" Text="Fund Source"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 343px; top: 161px; position: absolute" ReadOnly="True">University of Canberra</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 107px; top: 206px; position: absolute" Text="Emplyee Type"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 102px; top: 248px; position: absolute" Text="Employment Basis"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 342px; top: 248px; position: absolute; width: 127px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 126px; top: 291px; position: absolute" Text="Level"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 126px; top: 333px; position: absolute" Text="Units"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 342px; top: 334px; position: absolute; width: 128px">
            <asp:ListItem>Choose One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>FTE ( Continuing/Fixed-Term)</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Total Hours</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 96px; top: 375px; position: absolute" Text="Total Hours / FTE"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 340px; top: 374px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 122px; top: 414px; position: absolute" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 340px; top: 413px; position: absolute" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 120px; top: 456px; position: absolute" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 338px; top: 451px; position: absolute" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 118px; top: 498px; position: absolute" Text="Cost Basis"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 336px; top: 497px; position: absolute; width: 128px">
            <asp:ListItem>Choose One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Cost Recovery</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Cost Recovery + Grand Preperation</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Engagment Rate</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Government (State &amp; Fedral)</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Private Industry</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Back" OnClientClick="JavaScript:window.history.back(1);return false;" OnClick="Button1_Click1" style="z-index: 1; left: 361px; top: 565px; position: absolute"></asp:Button>
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 438px; top: 566px; position: absolute" Text="Save" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" style="z-index: 1; left: 514px; top: 567px; position: absolute" Text="Next" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 321px; top: 18px; position: absolute"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 344px; top: 294px; position: absolute; width: 126px; height: 16px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" style="z-index: 1; left: 345px; top: 209px; position: absolute; width: 126px">
            <asp:ListItem>Please Select One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Professional</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Academic</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't included `else if (value == "Casual")` or `else if (value == "Sessional")`

Comment: Oh god i was trying to test it if it works ill try adding all the other conditions and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding items in drop down 2 with value of that listitem as string.Empty and you are checkin value which is empty.

try below change

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    var value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    if (value == "Professional")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select One", "Please Select One"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Continuing - Professional", "Continuing - Professional"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Fixed Term", "Fixed Term"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Casual", "Casual"));
    }
    else if (value == "Academic")
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select One", "Please Select One"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Continuing - Academic", "Continuing - Academic"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Fixed Term", "Fixed Term"));
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Sessional", "Sessional"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill check it now and get back at you

Comment: Ok i tried so didnt work exactly same problem where the code reads dropsdownlist1 and shows what ever item depending on the selections but dropdownlist5 refuse to show the items depending on  selection in dropdownlist2

Comment: @DharyAlmousa its not working because you need to set AutoPostBack="True" for DropDownList2 then only SelectedIndexChanged event will be fire here. also you need to change code as I have suggested

Comment: But one more thing the list keeps stacking everytime i change the selection how can i fix that

Comment: you can use UpdatePanel for partial post back instead of whole page post back. that will not refresh page from UI

Comment: Not sure how to do so is there any other way to make it clear the items everytime a new selection is made

Comment: if you want to clear all controls then you can do by assigning them String.Empty value every time after save click